# External Data Source via GraphQL - what happens if there is a new field

Tags: externalobjects, graphql

If I have a GraphQL endpoint setup to be consumed by Salesforce as an External Data Source, will Salesforce detect changes to fields?

For example, let's say my GraphQL endpoint published an object like "Scores" with fields: Id, Name, Value.

Salesforce is connected to this GraphQL endpoint and configured so these fields are part of a Salesforce Object called Scores.

Later, another field is added like "Weight". What needs to happen in Salesforce to make that field appear?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ext_data_sync_database.htm&type=5